# Why is newList an empty array at this.setState({ filteredStudents: newList });?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-props, react-state-management

I am creating a simple React.js app and trying to create an input box that "live" filters results from an array of data, controlling what is displayed on the page in real time.

The step that filters the data display state is failing and emptying the state instead.

I have everything confirmed as far as I can tell to be working correctly elsewhere on the component aside from the part of my code that is handling this behavior.

My function that is supposed to filter and refresh the "filteredStudents" state (that is connected to what is displayed on the page).

When this function is triggered by the page however, "newList" (variable on line 2) is empty and while the page does not fail, the "filteredStudents" state is now empty. I assume this means that I have implemented the ".includes" steps on line 7 & 8 incorrectly but have not been able to correct it.

```
listFilter = () => {
    let newList = [];
    let search = this.state.search;
    let list = this.state.filteredStudents;
    if (this.state.search !== "") {
       for (let i = 0; i > list.length; i++) {
            let checkFirst = list[i].firstName.includes(search);
            let checkLast = list[i].lastName.includes(search);
            if (checkFirst === true || checkLast === true) {
                newList.push(list[i]);
            }
        }
        this.setState({ filteredStudents: newList });
    } else {
        let resetStudents = this.state.students;
        this.setState({ filteredStudents: resetStudents });
    }
}
```

I am trying to more or less replicate this behavior exactly as I found in this example:

https://codepen.io/pjmtokyo/pen/ZGVjVV

but I have not been able to. The function as written simply empties the array. I assume there is an error in my implementation of the ".includes" steps on line 7 & 8 but I have not been able to fix it.

Comment: Please edit your question's title to read something similar to: "_Why is `newList` an empty array at `this.setState({ filteredStudents: newList });`?_"

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to invert that comparison sign here:

`for (let i = 0; i > list.length; i++) {`

Looks like it should be:

`for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {`

You're practically not iterating over anything.

Comment: I now have a different issue but this moved me forward! I will work with this and see if I can finish up, this may now reveal an issue elsewhere thank you.